# file permissions are not changing even with root access - kali linux

Tags: permissions, kali-linux, root

I've got a strange problem with my dual boot system (windows and kali linux) I login to the root account but when I try to change the permissions of any file , I just can't ! it gives me no error or permission denied but it just won't change. when I check permissions it looks like nothing has happened to the file. I've tried using chown command with root terminal , sudo command and trying it with another account in the root group .

I also searched the web and saw some other people having the same problem but they had no practical way to fix this. don't know what to do.

thank you all !

Answer (score 0):

NTFS-file-system doesn't support the UNIX-like permissions. For Linux use NTFS-drivers to handle NTFS-partitions, so you can mount them and access the data stored on them.

You can also assign permissions to a single user by using the uid and/or the gid options together with the umask, or fmask and dmask options. Example for fstab-entry:

/dev/sdxY /home/user/mnt ntfs-3g rw,uid=1000,umask=775 0 0
This will affect all files and folders on the NTFS-partition.

On Kali linux NTFS-3G should be installed by default.